# Converter de String para Json no Java EE

Tags: java, json

Estou recebendo uma String em um .jsp e gostaria de convertê-la para JSON, para assim, acessar os valores da mesma. Já procurei por tudo, mas não consegui solucionar o meu problema, pois nao consgo acessar o valor do campo. Por favor, se puderem me ajudar, ficarei muito agradecido, sou ovo usando JSONs.

Abaixo segue o meu código:

//ENVIO O JSON NO FORMATO STRING

```
    var ItensVenda_String = JSON.stringify(ItensArray);
    var dadosDoForm_String = JSON.stringify(dadosDoForm);

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"http://localhost:8080/ProjBiltiful/cadastrarVenda.jsp",
            data: {data : ItensVenda_String},
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
              alert("Compra registrada com sucesso");
            }
       });
```

//RECEBENDO OS DADOS COMO STRING, TENTANDO PASSAR PARA JSON E ACESSAR OS CAMPOS

```
String dados = request.getParameter("data");

//System.out.println(dados);

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(dados.toString()); 
object.get("cbarras");
System.out.println(object.get("cbarras"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma biblioteca que realize o parse para você como Jackson dataBind ou GSON.
[Exemplos Utilizando Jackson](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)

[Exemplos Uitlizando GSON](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Basicamente é:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = dados.toString(); // Sua string em JSON
SuaClasse obj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, SuaClasse.class); //Faz a conversão para seu objeto
```

Depois de fazer o parse voce pega as propriedades normalmente, exemplo

```
obj.getCodigoBarras();
```

Comment: Devo assumir que o tipo de `dados` seja também `SuaClasse`?